# XSLT: Xpath to count items with attribute value matching another specific sibling

Tags: xslt, xpath, count

I have the following (simplified; there are more Property-Lines) XML-File that I need to process by XSLT:

```
<Collection Name="Columns" Type="OutputColumn">
<SubRecord>
    <Property Name="Name">SID</Property>
    <Property Name="SqlType">BigInt</Property>
    <Property Name="Derivation">inputstream1.SID</Property>
    <Property Name="Description">Main key</Property>
</SubRecord>
<SubRecord>
    <Property Name="Name">name</Property>
    <Property Name="SqlType">Char</Property>
    <Property Name="Derivation">inputstream2.name</Property>
    <Property Name="Description">Surname</Property>
</SubRecord>
    <SubRecord>
    <Property Name="Name">street</Property>
    <Property Name="SqlType">Char</Property>
    <Property Name="Derivation">inputstream1.streetname + inputstream1.number</Property>
    <Property Name="Description">Full street</Property>
</SubRecord></Collection>
```

I now need to know two things as a variable in XSLT to decide what to do further in an if-Condition:

1. Is there at least one SubRecord where substring-after(Derivation, '.') matches the sibling Property "Name" (so like in the first two SubRecords)?
2. Is there at least one SubRecord where substring-after(Derivation, '.') does not match the sibling Property "Name" (so like in the third SubRecord)?

I tried to do this by Xpath with the Count()-Functionality but simply can't figure out how to do the comparison to the sibling Property node with "Name" as it's name...I'm also open for other ideas if you know an alternative to Count().

Comment: You need to say whether this is XSLT 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0. It affects the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understood the issue, so check below and let me know if it's not what you actually want

First can be done with below `XPath`:

```
boolean(//SubRecord[substring-after(./Property[@Name="Derivation"]/text(), '.')=./Property[@Name="Name"]/text()])
```

This should return `true` because `XPath` matches first two `SubRecord` elements.

Using `not()` should allow to return `true` because `XPath` matches third `SubRecord` element:

```
boolean(//SubRecord[not(substring-after(./Property[@Name="Derivation"]/text(), '.')=./Property[@Name="Name"]/text())])
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly what I needed!